# MD5 Message Digest from SUN, <in progress>

Tags: ubuntu, md5, java, xubuntu

I try to get MD5 string using Java, but the function below return string `"MD5 Message Digest from SUN, <in progress>"`:

```
public String hash(String value) {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return md.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm using OpenJDK on Xubuntu. Why I get this message? Is there a way to get MD5 hash using this setup?

Comment: What message? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Please add the error message

Comment: Oh, and *don't* call `toString` on a byte array. Really bad idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet message from the Title of the question

Comment: @Encyclopedia it's in the title.

Comment: The whole of it? Part of it? Where are you seeing the message? You should make the question much, much clearer.

Comment: @JonSkeet it's not byte array it's MessageDigest object.

Comment: @jcubic: Ah, true. And is calling `toString()` on it useful? Shouldn't you be calling `digest()` and using the result?

Comment: @JonSkeet digest return byte array and I want a String.

Comment: @jcubic: Right, but the byte array *is the digest*. That's the useful bit of information. So how do you want to convert that into a string? Do you want a hex representation? Base64? Something else?

Comment: @JonSkeet hex string, the same as md5sum command.

Comment: @jcubic: Right - so take the byte array returned by `digest()`, and turn that into hex. If you don't know how to do that, search Stack Overflow - there are lots of questions about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution that work,

```
public String byteToHexString(byte[] input) {
    String output = "";
    for (int i=0; i<input.length; ++i) {
        output += String.format("%02X", input[i]);
    }
    return output;
}

public String hash(String value) {
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        return byteToHexString(md.digest(value.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [commons-codec.jar](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/codec/binaries/). Check the [API](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html).

```
String value = "YourValue";
System.out.println(DigestUtils.md5Hex( value ));
```